# Postgres reopens closed processes on Mac. How to solve?

Tags: postgresql, process, macos

I tried to terminate Postgres on Mac in various ways. I used commands in the terminal: `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop` , `brew services stop postgresql` , `systemctl stop postgres` . Did not work. The `kill -9` command I didn't try, because I read that it was dangerous. The PostgreSQL.pref.pane program, which starts and stops Postgre servers, did not provide a solution for this either. The command `sudo pkill -u postgres` worked for most processes, but over time the processes reopen. Is there a way not to reopen?

Comment: How did you install PostgreSQL, and have you checked the log and seen if the shutdown is completing? It can take a little while if the shutdown checkpoint has to sync a lot of data.

Comment: I installed using the download of the official site of Postgres. I've seen the termination of processes using Activity Monitor. And about the quantity of data, there is no data to sync.